# Node.js "net" connections load balancing

Tags: node.js, sockets, chat

I am researching Node.js net library's potential to implement a chat server. I am very much new to node.js. I was wondering how client connections to net TCP server can be load balanced across multiple servers (to handle a large load) and a message can be sent to all connections across the servers. Are there any servers available which can help with this? or should I look into socket.io or other libraries for the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a similar problem when developing [Mote.io](http://mote.io) and decided to go with a hosted solution instead of building a load balancer. Dealing with this problem is pretty difficult as you need to sync data across servers or load balance your clients to the same instance to make sure they get all the same messages.

Socket.io won't help much specifically. You would need to implement redis, some other data sync or load balancing app.

PubNub will take care of this as well. The backend is responsible for syncing messages, load balancing, etc at an abstract level so all you do is supply a channel name and PubNub will ensure that all clients in that channel get the message.

## Real-time Chat Apps in 10 Lines of Code

[image]

```
Enter Chat and press enter
<div><input id=input placeholder=you-chat-here /></div>

Chat Output
<div id=box></div>

<script src=http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js></script>
<script>(function(){
var box = PUBNUB.$('box'), input = PUBNUB.$('input'), channel = 'chat';
PUBNUB.subscribe({
    channel  : channel,
    callback : function(text) { box.innerHTML = (''+text).replace( /[<>]/g, '' ) + '<br>' + box.innerHTML }
});
PUBNUB.bind( 'keyup', input, function(e) {
    (e.keyCode || e.charCode) === 13 && PUBNUB.publish({
        channel : channel, message : input.value, x : (input.value='')
    })
} )
})()</script>
```